# Will this Ruby code use non-blocking I/O under Puma?

Tags: multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, blocking, puma

I'm investigating some bottlenecks in a legacy Rails app. Among other things, it makes some HTTP requests to (firewalled) back-end servers and streams the response to the client, using objects of the following class as the controller response body:

```
class Streamer
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def each 
    client = HTTPClient.new
    client.receive_timeout = 7200
    client.send_timeout = 3600
    client.connect_timeout = 7200
    client.keep_alive_timeout = 3600

    client.get_content(@url) { |chunk|
      yield chunk
    }

  end
end
```

I'm a novice where it comes to Ruby I/O and threading, and I'm not all that expert in Rails either. The design assumption seems to be that this (running on MRI) is only going to lock the interpreter once per chunk, and that other threads can execute while data is either coming in from the `HTTPClient`, or going out to the browser -- is that assumption valid? Or is this code going to starve Puma's other threads?

Comment: you should consider falcon framework. Its non blocking and can stream data to the client. also you may have to switch to a async HTTP client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is both yes and no, mostly because the terminology in the question is somewhat unclear.

Blocking IO means that IO is waiting for data. `HTTPClient` uses blocking IO. It waits for data to become available and only returns after the data was received.

Non-blocking IO means that the IO layer returns immediately, even if no data is present (often with the error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK).

The `HTTPClient` module blocks the control flow, waiting for the HTTP server's response.

However, this doesn't prevent other threads from running in "parallel" (or, in the case of Ruby MRI, interleaved).

> The design assumption seems to be that this (running on MRI) is only going to lock the interpreter once per chunk, and that other threads can execute while data is either coming in from the HTTPClient, or going out to the browser -- is that assumption valid?

In general, the assumption is correct (or close enough that it doesn't matter).

The GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) in Ruby MRI enforces a single thread execution for Ruby code. It prevents true parallelism and is reminiscent of the multi-treaded model used by single-core CPU machines.

However, since the IO code is performed outside the GIL, other threads will run while the IO is waiting for incoming data (blocking on `write`, `read` or `select`).

In general, Ruby will manage thread scheduling to interleave Ruby thread execution, allowing for concurrent execution (though not parallel execution).

> Or is this code going to starve Puma's other threads?

I'm not sure what you mean by starvation...

The code will starve Puma's thread **pool**, but the threads themselves will continue to run unhindered.

To clarify:

Puma has a thread pool for HTTP requests and task handling. The number of threads is limited.

The HTTPClient thread will be "stuck", waiting for IO completion and will not return to the thread pool, diminishing the pool (as a whole) and possibly causing resource starvation.

For example, if all the threads are waiting for an HTTPClient response, no requests would be handled until a thread becomes available again (the HTTPClient and the rest of the work finished).

On the other hand, the thread itself will allow other threads to run concurrently, using interleaved scheduling. So, the other threads don't starve, but Puma as a whole might.

Comment: I read patron release then GVL(https://github.com/toland/patron#performance-with-parallel-requests). does every http client release the GVL? some clients are pure ruby(HTTPClient) or based on net::http(HTTParty)

Comment: @OshanWisumperuma : The [core Ruby code releases the GIL (global instruction lock) when calling system IO](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/io.c#L1139)... at least, that's the general idea. This basically means that any Ruby based client will release the GIL during IO system calls. However, if the client is a C extension, then it really depends how it was written. I would expect a decent C extension to release the GIL, but it's really up to the developer.

Comment: @OshanWisumperuma - specifically, I skimmed the C and Ruby code for Patron and [found the code the releases the GIL](https://github.com/toland/patron/blob/92f20fac4810b9900b1a8d990804967dcc3ac621/ext/patron/session_ext.c#L803-L806).

Comment: To anyone who wants to find out the correct line number that @Myst referred above, here is the link with commit's SHA hash instead of master branch: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/05313c9/io.c#L1136